# Combine different joins in one query with groups and sums

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to calculate two quantities (sum1 and sum2) and subtract sum1 from sum2 for a column called tqty. Here is how sum1 is calculated:

```
SELECT tblStockMaster.SmName                           AS StockMaster,
       SUM(isnull(tblPurchaseOrderD.TotalQuantity, 0)) AS sum1
FROM   tblStockMaster
       LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseOrderD
         ON tblPurchaseOrderD.StockControl = tblStockMaster.SmName
GROUP  BY tblStockMaster.SmName
```

and result

> ```
> itemname                           sum1         
> ACTIVE MAPE 1                       0          
> DEVELOPMENTAL READING 2             2         
> EDUCATIONAL TECHNOLOGY 2            3        
> FACILITATING LEARNING 2             1          
> GRAMAMAR AND COMPOSITION            3        
> HUMANITIES AND DIGITAL ARTS         0        
> INTRODUCTIORY MEDICAL PHYSICS FOR   1          
> PHILLIPINE HISTORY AND GOVERMENT    0
> ```

and here's sum2:

```
SELECT tblStockMaster.SmName                       AS StockMaster,
       SUM(isNull(tblReceivingD.TotalQuantity, 0)) AS sum2
FROM   tblStockMaster
       LEFT JOIN tblReceivingD
         ON tblReceivingD.StockControlR = tblStockMaster.SmName
GROUP  BY tblStockMaster.SmName
```

and result

> ```
> itemname                                                      sum2    
> ACTIVE MAPE 1                                                   0        
> DEVELOPMENTAL READING 2                                         0          
> EDUCATIONAL TECHNOLOGY 2                                        0 
> FACILITATING LEARNING 2                                         0         
> GRAMAMAR AND COMPOSITION                                      396 
> HUMANITIES AND DIGITAL ARTS                                     0           
> INTRODUCTIORY MEDICAL PHYSICS FOR HEALTH                      200 
> PHILLIPINE HISTORY AND GOVERMENT WORKBOOK 6th EDIT              0
> ```

and I want the result:

> ```
> itemname                                             Sum1       sum2     tqty    
> ACTIVE MAPE 1                                         0           0         0 
> DEVELOPMENTAL READING 2                               2           0        -2 
> EDUCATIONAL TECHNOLOGY 2                              3           0        -3 
> FACILITATING LEARNING 2                               1           0        -1 
> GRAMAMAR AND COMPOSITION                              3         396       393
> HUMANITIES AND DIGITAL ARTS                           0           0         0   
> INTRODUCTIORY MEDICAL PHYSICS FOR HEALTH              1         200       199 
> PHILLIPINE HISTORY AND GOVERMENT WORKBOOK 6th EDIT    0           0         0
> ```

I'm trying to combine sum1 and sum2 to get a result like the above.

Comment: Please sort out the formatting of this question. Use the `{}` icon to format as code (and for formatting tables).

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. Placing major statement clauses (e.g. `FROM`, `WHERE`) on separate, indented lines helps readability. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. `<blockquote><pre>` is a good way of structuring output (until such time as SO supports `<samp>`). Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH PO
     AS (SELECT SUM(TotalQuantity) AS sum1,
                StockControl       AS SmName
         FROM   tblPurchaseOrderD
         GROUP  BY StockControl),
     R
     AS (SELECT SUM(TotalQuantity) AS sum2,
                StockControlR      AS SmName
         FROM   tblReceivingD
         GROUP  BY StockControlR)
SELECT tblStockMaster.SmName             AS StockMaster,
       ISNULL(sum1, 0)                   AS sum1,
       ISNULL(sum2, 0)                   As sum2,
       ISNULL(sum2, 0) - ISNULL(sum1, 0) as tqty
FROM   tblStockMaster
       LEFT JOIN PO
         ON PO.SmName = tblStockMaster.SmName
       LEFT JOIN R
         ON R.SmName = tblStockMaster.SmName
```

Comment: After reviewing, my answer turned out essentially same as yours, so I deleted it. But then I must say, there's something that can be improved about your answer. Namely, you don't need `GROUP BY` in the main select, don't you think? As well as `MAX`s, of course.

Comment: @Andriy - Good point. I don't know what I was thinking there!

Answer (score 0):

Could this help?

```
 select StockMaster, sum1, sum2, sum2-sum1 as tqtyfrom
(SELECT tblStockMaster.SmName                           AS StockMaster,
       SUM(isnull(tblPurchaseOrderD.TotalQuantity, 0)) AS sum1
FROM   tblStockMaster
       LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseOrderD
         ON tblPurchaseOrderD.StockControl = tblStockMaster.SmName
GROUP  BY tblStockMaster.SmName
)A
inner join
(
SELECT tblStockMaster.SmName                       AS StockMaster,
       SUM(isNull(tblReceivingD.TotalQuantity, 0)) AS sum2
FROM   tblStockMaster
       LEFT JOIN tblReceivingD
         ON tblReceivingD.StockControlR = tblStockMaster.SmName
GROUP  BY tblStockMaster.SmName )B
on A.StockMaster = B.StockMaster
```

The `inner join` might change to `Left` or `Right` according to how your entities are related to each other

Comment: ok thanks i will try sir thanks for help ill post when i got error

Answer (score -1):

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "tblPurchaseOrderD.TotalQuantity" could not be bound.

i got this error when you post this thanks for post it help so much hope cant fix this

```
WITH PO
     AS (SELECT SUM(tblPurchaseOrderD.TotalQuantity) AS sum1,
                StockControl                         AS SmName
         FROM   tblPurchaseOrderD
         GROUP  BY StockControl),
     R
     AS (SELECT SUM(tblPurchaseOrderD.TotalQuantity) AS sum2,
                StockControlR                        AS SmName
         FROM   tblReceivingD
         GROUP  BY StockControlR)
SELECT tblStockMaster.SmName                       AS StockMaster,
       ISNULL(MAX(sum1), 0)                        AS sum1,
       ISNULL(MAX(sum2), 0)                        As sum2,
       ISNULL(MAX(sum2), 0) - ISNULL(MAX(sum1), 0) as tqty
FROM   tblStockMaster
       LEFT JOIN PO
         ON PO.SmName = tblStockMaster.SmName
       LEFT JOIN R
         ON R.SmName = tblStockMaster.SmName
GROUP  BY tblStockMaster.SmName
```

i got error sir --->Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The multi-part identifier "tblPurchaseOrderD.TotalQuantity" could not be bound. <----this one

sorry sir i think i got it in your post! thanks sir it help so much i got it in your post thanks it help so much........

Comment: Whoops a copy paste error on my part. I shouldn't have left the table name in. Fixed now.